# Protecting imported modules from being corrupted by third party code

Tags: python

If my code uses third party modules that cannot be trusted, is there anything to prevent situation like this:

UntrustedModule.py:

```
import random

random.random = lambda : 4
```

MyModule.py:

```
import random
import UntrustedModule

print (random.random())
```

where just importing this module breaks assumptions about other, unrelated ones?

Comment: Untrusted modules can do much more that just replace functions and such. Don't run untrusted modules.

Comment: That modification looks fine (see http://xkcd.com/221/). ;)

Comment: Python isn't really designed to prevent this. If this is a requirement you'd be better off either using a language that is (like Lua or Javascript), or create a sandboxing scheme that runs the modules in another process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't have any such guarantee in Python, at least not in the CPython implementation. When you import a module its code is run, and it has **full access** to every part of the interpreter (and likely big parts of your system). No way to avoid this. It is unwise to ever load untrusted code, because there is so much it can do.

However you may be interested in running the process in an isolated process, and only communicate with it by IPC. This is a huge topic and it depends on the degree of isolation you need and how much you trust the external code.

---

PyPy implements some [sandboxing features](http://pypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/sandbox.html). It's not as simple as just "turning sandboxing on" but it's one of many ways to isolate untrusted code.

Answer (score -1):

You can do a

```
reload(random)
```

in order to reload it from source resp. to restore it as it is intended to be.

Comment: I guess it is concern that security matters are overlooked, as OP was talking about "untrusted code".

Comment: (Untrusted code could plug into the import machinery itself and make reload useless)

Answer (score -1):

Python will import in the order of searching the local path (the directory from which the script was executed) first, then any paths listed in the PYTHONPATH environment variable.

A better solution would be to inspect and write tests against your untrusted module.

Comment: "A better solution would be to inspect and write tests against your untrusted module." - not really. That just means you're betting you're more clever than potential attackers.

Comment: @millimoose: hence where the inspection comes in. If the module is truly untrusted, then it's best not to be used.